# How to crash/inject fault in a Virtual Machine(VM)?

Tags: linux, crash, cloud, virtual-machine, digital-ocean

We are working on VMs on cloud. We would like to crash or make a VM to fail in Digital Ocean cloud. 
Can you please let us know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of, is to crash the linux kernel that will crash the VM. You can try out this if it fits your requirement.

Approach:

Use the sysrq-trigger cmd to crash the kernel:

`echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`